# Problems with Threading in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Background:
I have a program that is processing lots of database records, and generating tasks to do. (In this case creating user accounts in AD).
Part of this is to create the user directories, for profiles and home directories, and setting the permissions on them.
This needs to wait until the ad account has replicated across all of our DC's.

So, my program will have a separate thread responsible for creating the directories, that will process a queue populated from the main thread.

I've done some research on Threading and come up with the following code pattern:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
Dim worker As Object
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    worker = New workerObj(AddressOf resultcallback)
    Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf worker.mainloop)
End Sub

Public Sub resultcallback(ByVal item As String)
    Outbox.AppendText(item)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    worker.addItem(inbox.Text)
End Sub
End Class

Public Delegate Sub resultcallback(ByVal item As String)

Public Class workerObj
Private myQueue As New Queue(Of String)
Private myCallback As resultcallback
Dim item As String = "nout"

Public Sub New(ByVal callbackdelegate As resultcallback)
    myCallback = callbackdelegate
End Sub

Public Sub mainloop()
    While True
        If myQueue.Count > 0 Then
            item = myQueue.Dequeue()
            myCallBack(item)
        End If
        Thread.Sleep(5000)
    End While
End Sub

Public Sub addItem(ByVal item As String)
    myQueue.Enqueue(item)
End Sub
End Class
```

Problem:
On the line   Dim t as new Thread.....

```
Error   1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' is most specific for these arguments:
'Public Sub New(start As System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart)': Not most specific.
'Public Sub New(start As System.Threading.ThreadStart)': Not most specific. n:\visual studio 2013\Projects\ThreadTest\ThreadTest\Form1.vb   7   13  ThreadTest
```

Can anyone help tell me where I have gone wrong?
Cheers.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with threading. You should check the documentation of the method you are trying to use before writing the code and ensure it compiles. Moreover, I'd suggest you use tasks instead of raw threads as they simplify concurrent programming a lot and they help you avoid a lot of the gotchas of using threads. Eg, creating a thread is expensive so it should be avoided in favour of using ThreadPool threads. Task.Run does this under the covers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads do not have a public constructor, you need to call Thread.Start. I'd suggest you don't do that though. Writing thread-safe code is tricky enough when you do know about multithreaded programming.

Eg in your code you modify a Queue from two different threads without locking. Queue isn't thread safe and you can corrupt the queue. You should lock access to it or use ConcurrentQueue which *is* thread-safe. Another error is trying to modify a TextBox from another thread - this will lead to an Exception because only the UI thread is allowed to modify UI controls.

A better option though is to use the [ActionBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class from the DataFlow library which already does what you want: queue requests and process them in one or more separate threads.

Your code can be as simple as this:

```
Dim myFileWorker=New ActionBlock(Of string)(Function(path) =>DoSomething(path))

For Each somePath As String in ListWithManyPaths
    myFileWorker.Post(somePath)
Next somePath

myFileWorker.Complete()
myFileWorker.Completion.Wait()
```

By default only one path will be processed at a time. To process multiple paths you pass an [ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) object with the desired MaxDegreeOfParallelism:

```
Dim options=New ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() With { .MaxDegreeOfParallelism=5}
Dim myFileWorker=New ActionBlock(Of String) Function(path) DoSomething(path),options)
```

Comment: The callback was meant to pass the data back to the main thread (ui) to update the textbox.
So, with ActionBlock, how would I call the mainloop sub to read the conncurentqueue object?

Comment: Or would I not need a queue?  This will be generating thousands of accounts, so I don't want spawn thousands of threads, (hence my idea to use some sort of queue, with just 2 threads of control.  One producing the data, and one consuming it

Comment: ActionBlock queues all incoming messages so you don't have to queue anything.  Controlling the number of threads is as easy as setting MaxDegreeOfParallelism=2. To update the UI you either use a callback and Invoke, or use the [Progress(Of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class in .NET 4.5 to post messages from multiple threads to the UI thread. This allows you to use complex progress events, queue multiple events without blocking the workers and decouples the workers from the actual method/callback that does reporting.

Comment: Moreover, the DataFlow library allows you to send the output of one block to another block, thus creating a pipeline of blocks.